# Can not add Relationship to contact post CiviCRM 4.7.30 upgrade

Tags: relationships

Although, I had orignally thought the issue was on the "Webform CiviCRM Integration" module end, further testing shows it is likely an issue on the CiviCRM end since when I manually try to create the relationship I end up with a "spinning wheel" and a page refresh gives the following error:

"unknown relationship create error API (EntitySetting, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"

Any insight?

Comment: have you created any Relationships between Contact Sub-types then perhaps deleted the Contact sub-type?

Comment: No, there has been no changes in regards to Contact Sub-types

Comment: Solved - After more testing, I have discovered the issue is with the CiviCRM extension "Related Permissions Module (nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions)". Once disabled, the ability to add relationships between two contacts resumed.

Comment: I would be interested to know how to replicate this. That extension - one of ours - is in use on a lot of sites running v complex configurations. Was it the latest version?

Comment: Hi Peter, would be happy to provide any info you require but can tell you I tested yesterday with a fresh install of Drupal 7.57, CiviCRM 4.7.30 and Related Permissions Module 1.3 .

Comment: I just installed the extension (along with nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting) on a 4.7.30 site (drupal) and my relationships tab is loading fine. I then enabled 2nd degree relationships at civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 and rechecked and Relationship tab loaded fine. I then set some Relationship Types to 'always Permission A" and it still loaded. I then deleted a Rel. Type that had 'always Permission' set on it just in case, and it still loaded. Finding it hard to find the particular scenario to get this to fail. Do you want to reenable then try and get any errors from the page via Inspect

Comment: Just re-tested and if I also install and enable "nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting" I am able to set a relationship between contacts.

Comment: okay - note that extension is a requirement of relatedpermission - though i also tested without it and still wasn't getting the problem but glad we solved it. can you pls accept the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have extension nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting enabled as it is a requirement of nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermission

Comment: Perfect. That was an issue that occurred. I had nz.co.fuzion.entitysetting and the issue is gone.